# I'm a really beginner in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Facing this error of Unexpected character  while using expo .
Am new to react native and expo.

error: SyntaxError: .\node_modules\expo\build\Expo.fx.js: Unexpected character ''. (1:0)

[here is the Expo.fx.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joUwf.png)

this is my package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "dogecoin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mindinventory/react-native-tab-bar-interaction": "^2.2.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^18.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "expo": "^49.0.7",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Are you using Mac OS or Windows?

Comment: @MichaelBahl I'm using windows 10